# IE10 debugger console not showing js output

Tags: internet-explorer, debugging, console

Previously my IE10 debugger console would output the results of any js script I ran in the console, regardless of whether I was on a break point or not. The script was run in the global scope. After mucking around with some code and debugging, I seem to have lost that ability.

Not on a break point:

[image: Not on a debug point]

On a break point:

[image: On break point]

Previously, both cases would look like the bottom picture. Any way to restore this?